# record files that a process opens

Tags: linux, bash

I have a program that repeatedly  opens many files from a network drive, and processes them. I would like to save these files locally to my harddrive. Is there a unix utility that returns a list of files that a process has opened?

Comment: Check `lsof` or `fuser`.

Comment: Might want to ask this one on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `ptrace(2)` system call; programs like: `dtrace(1)`, `strace(1)`, `truss(1)`; linker tricks with `LD_PRELOAD`